# Github not picking up change in code, can not commit

Tags: git, github

I have made a small change to code of a certain page which is held on github. It doesn't seem like the change that I made is big enough for git to pick this change up, so I can not commit the change (the change was so small, it was only changing InsertLinkCircularLoopCheckTemplate to InsertLinkCircularLoopCheck on one line in filename modifyobservation.aspx.vb). Is there anyway to force my file over the one on git with this change?

Comment: i mean,you want to commit your file to github repo ?

Comment: Please stop writing "GitHub" when you mean "git". It's just like when your grandma say "I launch Internet" when she goes to Google. Please...

Comment: Note that there is no content change "too small" for git to pick up.  Even changing a single bit on a file will be noticed as a modified file by git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like this way,

```
git add yourfilename

git commit -m "message"
```

Comment: but if I do it that way, will it overwrite the file with the same name? That is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Srinivas's answer will overwrite (in that it will as a new version to) the file on GitHub.

Should you want the reverse, ie leave the version on GitHub unchanged, but have a local version (in your working tree) which will always overwrite the GitHub version even after a git pull, then you can ask for your local file to have its [modifications ignored](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-update-index.html#_using_8220_assume_unchanged_8221_bit) (while still being versioned).

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- /path/to/your/file
```